# Free Shipping if Subtotal greater than or equal $50?

Tags: magento-1.7

How can I add a coupon, Free Shipping if Subtotal greater than or equal $50?

I'm new to Magento.

I'm using v1.7.0.2

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried from Admin > System > Configuration > Shipping methods > Free shipping > Minimum Order Amount ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If you want free shipping only when a coupon is applied**

Create a shopping cart price rule (and add one or more coupon codes to it) with these conditions:
[image: conditions]

In the actions tab set `Free Shipping` to `For shipment with matching items`.

[image: actions]

Then go to `System->Configuration->Shipping Methods->Free Shipping` and for the field `Minimum Order Amount` fill in an outrageous value like `999999999`. Then save.
[image: free-shipping]

This will make the free shipping method available only when you submit the right coupon code.

**If you want free shipping for all orders above 50**
Skip the coupon creation part explained above and in the configuration panel for `Free Shipping` just fill 50 in the `Minimum Order Amount` field.

Comment: Got it solved. Steps are legit to follow.

Comment: @Marius I've tried above steps with Magento version 1.9.3.0 but its not working. I've created a shopping cart rule for $75 and Minimum Order Amount = 9999999999. But my cart shows UPS method only and not free shipping.

Comment: As you can see this is an almost 3 years old post. I have no idea if it works on the latest version.

Comment: @Marius Thanks for your reply. But do you have any idea? What could be the issue?

Comment: @Deeps. I don't sorry.

Answer (score 3):

goto adminpanel `system > configuration`

click on `shipping method` in the sidebar then select Free shipping

You can give **Minimum Order Amount** 50 in this field.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create one Shopping cart rule under the Promotions Menu - >Add New rule - > and in condition tab , you can add new condition like subtotal > $50 and add other information for hte coupon.
ONce this is done you can check on frontend ,like this coupon will only be valid if the subtotal is greater then the amount you added in that condition.

Thanks