# Magento shopping cart price rule & alert for nearest subtotal

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, alert

I want to build the rule which fulfill below rule.

Free shipping if over $100 or if they reach nearer $90 then give them option that buy $10 more for free delivery.

I set the first rule for free delivery Subtotal equals or greater than 100, but how i can display message or alert to get customer know that if their subtotal is $10 more. they are eligible for free delivery.

Answer (score 1):

get help from this [url](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17806/free-shipping-if-subtotal-greater-than-or-equal-50) to create shopping role.

For "if they reach nearer $90 then give them option that buy $10 more for free delivery" Go to template/checkout/cart.phtml and write bellow code where you need:

```
 if($OrderTotal = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal() < 100  )
  {
    $extra = ( 100 - $OrderTotal) ;
    echo $this->__('buy '.$extra.' more for free delivery.');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is pretty old but this is what I ended up doing:

```
    <?php
        $totalSum = $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
        if($totalSum < 100){
            $extra = (100 - $totalSum);
            echo $this->__('ADD &#36;' .$extra.' MORE - TO YOUR CART TO RECEIVE FREE TOTE.');
        }else{
            echo $this->__('TOTE WILL ARIVE WITH YOUR ORDER');
        }
    ?>
```